# Android JSon error "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2"

Tags: android, json, illegalstateexception

I am getting JSon data from a web service, the sample data is given below:

```
[
  {
    "SectionId": 1,
    "SectionName": "Android"
  }
]
```

When i try to convert it, it throws an error, i am doing it as:

```
Data data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonDataFromWebService, Data.class);
```

My Section Class is:

```
class Section
{
    public int SectionId;
    public String SectionName;
}

class Data {
    public List<Section> sections;
}
```

**The LogCat says:**

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error explains whats wrong... u r returning an array and not a JSon object

try as following:

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonStringReturnedByService);

Data sections = new Data();

for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
    Section s = new Section();
    JSONObject jsonSection = ja.getJSONObject(i);

    s.SectionId = Integer.ValueOf(jsonSection.getString("SectionId"));
    s.SectionName = jsonSection.getString("SectionName");

   //add it to sections list
   sections.add(s);
}

return sections;
```

Comment: This is a bad answer. Changing the way the API returns data is not always an option.

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to create an non-Array(Collection) object from a JSONArray. The error is pretty clear: GSON was expecting the beginning of an object but found the beginning of an array instead.

Take a look at the documentation page below to see how to work with Array and Collection types with GSON

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples

From the docs:

> Array Examples
>
> Gson gson = new Gson(); int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; String[] strings
>   = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
>
> (Serialization) gson.toJson(ints);     ==> prints [1,2,3,4,5]
>   gson.toJson(strings);  ==> prints ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
>
> (Deserialization) int[] ints2 = gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4,5]",
>   int[].class); 
>   ==> ints2 will be same as ints
>
> We also support multi-dimensional arrays, with arbitrarily complex
>   element types
>   Collections Examples
>
> Gson gson = new Gson(); Collection ints =
>   Lists.immutableList(1,2,3,4,5);
>
> (Serialization) String json = gson.toJson(ints); ==> json is
>   [1,2,3,4,5]
>
> (Deserialization) Type collectionType = new
>   TypeToken>(){}.getType(); Collection
>   ints2 = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType); ints2 is same as ints
>
> Fairly hideous: note how we define the type of collection
>   Unfortunately, no way to get around this in Java
>
> Collections Limitations
>
> Can serialize collection of arbitrary objects but can not deserialize
>   from it Because there is no way for the user to indicate the type of
>   the resulting object While deserializing, Collection must be of a
>   specific generic type All of this makes sense, and is rarely a problem
>   w> hen following good Java coding practices

Answer (score 0):

Use Section class only as follows:

```
Section[] sectionArray = new Gson().fromJson(jsonDataFromWebService, Section[].class);
for (Section section: sectionArray) {
     Log.e("Debug", section.toString());
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.