# App working in Gingerbread, throws NetworkOnMainThreadException in Honeycomb

Tags: android, json, http, http-get, arrays

I'm using the following function to get a JSON Array from a php webpage.

While this exact code works on the 2.3 version of the app, on the 3.0 version that I'm currently building it force-closes and gives me a weird error log.

Any help would be great...

Are there any particularities to Honeycomb as opposed to Gingerbread when using http posts and things like that?

```
    private void getNews(){
    try{
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.ace.ucv.ro/android/stiri.php?perpage=20");

    result = EntityUtils.toString(new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpGet).getEntity());

    JSONArray jsonMainArray = new JSONArray(result);


} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

And calling the function:

```
        getNews.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            getNews();
        }
    });
```

And the error log

```
02-26 16:06:42.218: W/dalvikvm(478): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:477)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at pirelli.app.ScanBarcode.getNews(ScanBarcode.java:46)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at pirelli.app.ScanBarcode.access$4(ScanBarcode.java:42)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at pirelli.app.ScanBarcode$5.onClick(ScanBarcode.java:164)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-26 16:06:42.247: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Not returning JSON in proper format. Make it correct, i think you should use CDATA whenever you want to return HTML string in response.

Comment: too lazy to search `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` on google ?

Comment: I'll try that, but I still don't understand how the exact same code works on my Gingerbread app that's already out and functional...

Comment: just use AsyncTask instead doing network operation on main thread

Comment: @Selvin thanks for that, no, I'm not too lazy...I'm hoping people with more experience can help me out, since I'm coding on my own and don't have anyone else to ask and...this is a forum for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441932/android-json-error-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array-at-line-1-column-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you looked for "NetworkOnMainThreadException" in El Goog, the first thing you get is the link to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). It states that this exception is since Api Level 11 (Honeycomb 3.0), that's why you were not getting it before. It also even links to the "Designing for Responsiveness" page. The proper way to do network operations is, like some of the commenters suggested, via an AsyncTask.

Comment: Yeap, I'm doing that now. Thanks for taking the time to answer.