# From SQLite to JSON Array

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, json, sqlite

So I have an SQLite table that is internally stored with an id, latitude, longitude, and time. I would like to send that table to my external SQL Server through a webservice. Populating a JSON Array with my SQLite data and passing that array to a webservice which then does some processing and stores it in the SQL Server seems like the best way to achieve this. I am confused as to the best way of populating the JSON array from my SQLite table. Could anyone provide some example code or maybe link to a tutorial?

Comment: Does this table have an associated model class? If it does, there are libraries available which would make serializing these objects into JSON very simple. Otherwise, you'll probably have to build the JSON array by hand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9465539/265167

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[to check you json "query"](http://json2csharp.com/)

[tutorial, oficial web page](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)