# JSON array parsing in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

Here is my JSON object and i want to parse it in android project

```
{
    "second": {
        "versionInfo": "0.20.3-dev",
        "compileDate": "Mon Mar 12 17:39:23 IST 2012",
        "compileUser": "suraj",
        "trackname": "tracker_localhost:localhost/127.0.0.1:48418"
    },
    "href": {
        "versionInfo": "null",
        "compileDate": "null",
        "compileUser": "null",
        "trackname": "null"
    },
    "first": {
        "key": "['trackname','versionInfo','compileDate','compileUser']"
    }
}
```

How to compile?
i want to first extract attributes of 'first' and using the attributes and then to extract parameters of 'second' using attributes of 'first'.

Comment: Have you considered using a JSON parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Comment: Also, you can make use of [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse this JSON String into Java object types and manipulate it. http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/

Comment: the best way would be to use Gson and let it do automatically for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441932/android-json-error-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array-at-line-1-column-2

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is done like that:

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(theString);
JSONObject first = jobj.getJSONObject("first");
JSONObject second = jobj.getJSONObject("second");
```

If you want more, take a look at the documentation of [JSON classes for android](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html).

**Edit**

Regarding the extraction of the array (in first->key):

```
String jStr = first.getString("key");
JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(jStr);
```

Comment: thanks....but how to get values from key 'key' in 'first' object....as there is only one key and value is array of attributes?

Comment: one at a time :). The value of "key" is NOT an array but a String (that contains a serialized JSON array). I will edit in a few minutes, but if you read the documentation it'll be easier for you in the future.

Comment: thank you very much....actually i am new to json and android thats why i dont know the exact concept.........anyway i will keep in mind your suggestion..and again thanks for help :)