# Android: string can't convert to JSONArray?

Tags: java, android, json, http

I can get a json response from json_encode from php and I was able to show it in my logcat in eclipse what the response was:

```
[{"idusers":"1","full_name":"Test Subject","get_email":"test_subject@gmail.com"},
{"idusers":"2","full_name":"Test Subject_2","get_email":"test_subject_2@gmail.com"}]
```

Now, I'm trying to

```
    //parse json data
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i =0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("idusers")+
                    ", Full Name: "+json_data.getString("full_name")+
                    ", Email: "+json_data.getString("get_email")
                    );
        }
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error parsin data "+e.toString());
    }
```

However, I'm getting an error saying that

`Error parsin data org.json.JSONException: Value testing of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Is there a way to fix the JSONArray problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a " missing towards the end of your String. Is that the cause of your problem, or is that just a typo?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441932/android-json-error-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array-at-line-1-column-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what happened. I had a string in the PHP document and wasn't being called. I had the word "testing", which was the word from the error. Once this "testing" was deleted, it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. A quote (") is missing in the "get_email" value in the 2nd array element.

Should be:

```
[
    {
        "idusers": "1",
        "full_name": "Test Subject",
        "get_email": "test_subject@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "idusers": "2",
        "full_name": "Test Subject_2",
        "get_email": "test_subject_2@gmail.com"}]
```

Comment: that's definitely just a typo. cause i'm getting a response from bufferreader

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a cast to the PHP variables being returned by JSON. Also, are you using json_encode?

```
$user_id = (int) $id;
$email = (string) $email;
```

Comment: This is what I'm passing through in my PHP file `while($get = $SQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $output[]=$get;
 }
             print(json_encode($output));`

Comment: So, I'm technically not really setting any variables, its just going directly towards the array. the datatype in mysql is varchar, does that have a difference? and the id is int.