# Cant able to parse JSON in android using url

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am getting `id` of the button from the button click using intent and that `id` should redirect to other webservice. I wrote a webservice which it works fine in browser. I'm not able to parse the json and not able to know where I went wrong

can anyone suggest me where I went wrong?

```
 Intent j = getIntent();
 int position = j.getExtras().getInt("id");
 String uri_book="http://apps.ADSFDS.com/service/details.php?bookid="+position;
 Log.i("uri", uri_book);
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(uri_book, "GET",params);
```

**EDIT :-** Format of Json String is like this

```
 {
"bookdetails": [
    {
        "bid": "3",
        "name": "Introducing Html5",
        "bookid": "3",
        "description": null,
        "image1": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41S-eXdQS4L._SL500_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-big,TopRight,35,-73_OU01_.jpg",
        "image2": "http://www.html5videoguide.net/presentations/HTML5_Video_LCA2011/book_index.png"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: what is the error you getting ..put the logcat log  here

Comment: you are getting json string from webservice or not?you have problem in parsing json string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441932/android-json-error-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array-at-line-1-column-2

Comment: put the logcat log here!