# Gson cannot deserialize List<Serializable>

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON I got from a server into its original POJO form. I know the original Object (I have the source of the server's code), but it seems I'm missing something.

Here is the minimal code sample I could assemble that illustrates my problem:

```
package mycompany.mypackage;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.InstanceCreator;

public class GsonSerializeTest {

    /* main method to illustrate the problem */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Serializable[] identifiers= {"ITEM",12345678,"abc.def.ghijkl.mnopqr",87654321};
        EntityUid uid = new GsonSerializeTest().new EntityUid(identifiers);
        Gson converter = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Serializable.class, new GsonSerializeTest().new SerializableInstanceCreator()).create();
        String json = converter.toJson(uid);
        System.out.println("Converted to string: " + json);
        EntityUid uid2 = converter.fromJson(json, EntityUid.class); // ERROR
        System.out.println("Converted back to object: " + uid2);
    }

    /* the POJO that gets serialized and fails while deserializing */
    public class EntityUid implements Serializable {
        private final List<Serializable> identifier = new ArrayList<Serializable>();

        public EntityUid(final Serializable... identifier) {
            for (Serializable partialIdentifier : identifier) {
                this.identifier.add(partialIdentifier);
            }
        }
    }

    /* Class for generating Serializable instances */
    public class SerializableInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<Serializable> {
        public Serializable createInstance(Type arg0) {
            return new String();
        }
    }
}
```

This prepares the EntityUid object, serializes it (just as the server does) into this:

```
Converted to string: {"identifier":["ITEM",12345678,"abc.def.ghijkl.mnopqr",87654321]}
```

and then tries to deserialize it into the original Object, but fails with the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 17
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
    at mycompany.mypackage.GsonSerializeTest.main(GsonSerializeTest.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 17
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
    ... 10 more
```

Could somebody please provide me a pointer on what might I be missing? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [Serializing and Deserializing Collection with Objects of Arbitrary Types](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types).

This below code will work though.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class GsonSerializeTest {

    /* main method to illustrate the problem */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] identifiers= {12345678,"ITEM","abc.def.ghijkl.mnopqr",87654321};
        EntityUid uid = new EntityUid(identifiers);
        Gson converter = new GsonBuilder().create();
        String json = converter.toJson(uid);
        System.out.println("Converted to string: " + json);
        EntityUid uid2 = converter.fromJson(json, EntityUid.class); // ERROR
        System.out.println("Converted back to object: " + uid2);
    }

    /* the POJO that gets serialized and fails while deserializing */
    public static class EntityUid  {
        private final List<Object> identifier = new ArrayList<Object>();

        public EntityUid(final Object... identifier) {
            for (Object partialIdentifier : identifier) {
                this.identifier.add(partialIdentifier);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "EntityUid [identifier=" + identifier + "]";
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I see correctly, you suggest that I change the EntityUid's identifier field into List<Object>. This would indeed solve the problem, but I don't have control over the server's code, I can just view it and use it. However, I'll try defining an EntityUid object in this way, and see if it works as intended.

Comment: I managed to create a new class based on the original, but mine contains a List of Objects (inspired by your answer) instead of a List of Serializables. This structure can then be used as a deserialization template for the given JSON. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below post it will help you.

[Android JSon error "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441932/android-json-error-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array-at-line-1-column-2).

**Collections Limitations:**

Can serialize collection of arbitrary objects but can not deserialize from it Because there is no way for the user to indicate the type of the resulting object While deserializing, Collection must be of a specific generic type All of this makes sense, and is rarely a problem when following good Java coding practices

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think List<Serializable> is indeed a specific type. In the linked question the JSON is an array, and the poster tries to deserialize it into an object, that fails for clear reasons. Previously I tried to deserialize this example into a List<Serializable>: `String input = "[\"ITEM\",12345678,\"abc.def.ghijkl.mnopqr\",87654321]";` and it worked perfectly (thus I think the collection is right as it is)